# Retrieve cursor in oracle JPA ()

Tags: jpa, plsql, java-stored-procedures

I can´t retrieve data from procedure in oracle using JPA @StoredProcedureQuery nor @StoredNamedProcedureQuery

PL/SQL

```
create or replace procedure p_get_plazas_activas(
p_c_resultado out pkg_zas_response.t_response
)
 IS

BEGIN

   IF p_c_resultado%ISOPEN THEN
        CLOSE p_c_resultado;
        END IF;
    OPEN p_c_resultado FOR

      select distinct pl.PLZ_S_ID_PLAZA,  pl.PLZ_S_PLAZA
        from  escaneo.pre_plazas pl, escaneo.pre_cos c
        where pl.PLZ_S_ID_PLAZA = c.COS_S_ID_PLAZA
        and   pl.PLZ_S_PROVEEDOR is null 
        and   pl.PLZ_N_STATUS = 1
        and   c.COS_N_ACTIVO = 1;  

end p_get_plazas_activas;
```

then in java

```
StoredProcedureQuery spq = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("p_get_plazas_activas");
List results = spq.getResultList();
```

i get next error

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: linea 1, columna 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P_GET_PLAZAS_ACTIVAS'
ORA-06550: linea 1, columna 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error Code: 6550
Call: BEGIN escaneo.p_get_plazas_activas(?); END;
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ResultSetMappingQuery()
```

Also i have tried with

```
spq.registeterStoredProcedureparameter(1, void.class, ParameterMode.INOUT)
```

Some advice??

Answer (score 0):

You didn't register the output parameter:

```
 spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
 //                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 //                             or whatever type is relevant here
```

You retrieve to output later using:

```
 int count = (Integer)spq.getOutputParameterValue(1);
 //^          ^^^^^^^
 // or whatever type is relevant to you
```